# How do I use GROUP BY so it orders by a particular column?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need to get a list of all the latest check-in times and check-out times from the following table:

```
Table: checkin_times

    +----------+-------------------------+---------------------+
    |  Person  | in_time                 | out_time            |
    +----------+-------------------------+---------------------+
    |  Bob     | 2015-08-10 07:15:00     | 2015-08-10 17:15:00 |
    |  Bob     | 2015-08-12 07:00:00     | NULL                |
    |  Geoff   | 2015-08-12 07:40:00     | 2015-08-12 17:40:00 |
    |  Bob     | 2015-08-11 07:15:00     | 2015-08-12 17:15:00 |
    |  Geoff   | 2015-08-10 07:00:00     | 2015-08-12 17:00:00 |
    +----------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

(Obviously `NULL` means that the person has not yet checked out.)

I'm not interested in the latest entries. So, for this example the output should be:

```
+----------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|  Person  | in_time                 | out_time            |
+----------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|  Bob     | 2015-08-12 07:00:00     | NULL                |
|  Geoff   | 2015-08-12 07:40:00     | 2015-08-12 17:40:00 |
+----------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

I've tried the following SQL:

```
SELECT person, MAX(in_time) AS in_time, MAX(out_time) AS out_time 
FROM checkin_times  
GROUP BY person
ORDER BY person;
```

But it doesn't handle the `NULL` properly and returns the latest *actual* date for the `out_time` instead.

Ideally I'd like the order of the `GROUP BY` to only ever consider the `in_time` when it determines sequence.

Comment: ORDER BY does *not* affect what is grouped and it does *not* affect the results of the select clause or aggregate functions therein. The problem with the "doesn't handle the NULL" lies in the aggregation function itself - any value is 'more max' than no value.

Comment: Why dont you remove MAX(out_time) AS out_time and replace it with out_time only from the query it will give the desired result.

Comment: @TarunUpadhyay It won't always be right. It will show the first result it finds, which may or may not be the latest time. I'll change my example to reflect this.

Comment: @Urbycoz in your changed example also the NULL corresponds to  MAX(in_time) so should work. Can you run the query once and check.

Comment: @TarunUpadhyay No. That will result in either 1) unpredictable behavior or 2) a rejected query.

Comment: @TarunUpadhyay It's runs ok, but it's not the right result. It shows the first in_time and out_time, instead of the latest ones.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correct you are trying to fetch all column values per each persons latest in_time.

Then first fetch the latest in_time and join them on all records.

**Example**:

```
mysql> select ct.person, ct.in_time, ct.out_time
    ->   from checkin_times ct
    ->   right join ( select person, max( in_time ) as in_time
    ->                 from checkin_times group by person ) it
    ->          on ct.person = it.person and ct.in_time=it.in_time;
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| person | in_time             | out_time            |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Bob    | 2015-08-12 07:00:00 | NULL                |
| Geoff  | 2015-08-12 07:40:00 | 2015-08-12 17:40:00 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d09dc/1)

Comment: Yes! This is what I'm after. Thank you. (Sorry it took so long for me to test.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ct.person, ct1.in_time, ct2.out_time 
FROM checkin_times AS ct
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(in_time) AS in_time, person 
    FROM checkin_times
    GROUP BY person
) AS ct1 ON ct1.person = ct.person
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT out_time, in_time, person 
    FROM checkin_times
) AS ct2 ON (ct2.person = ct1.person AND ct2.in_time = ct1.in_time)
ORDER BY ct.person
```

Comment: Sorry, that still seems to give the same result. It shows the latest out_time instead of showing NULL

Comment: This doesn't seem to be showing the latest times. I think it just uses the first one it finds.

Comment: I tried it and I can see it's not right. Exactly what it's doing is a bit harder to know.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` statement and also use `DATE()` or `CURDATE()` :

```
SELECT person, MAX(in_time) AS in_time, MAX(out_time) AS out_time 
FROM checkin_times
GROUP BY person
ORDER BY person, 
CASE WHEN out_time IS NULL
THEN DATE()
ELSE out_time
END;
```

Comment: What does the `WHERE enabled=1` bit do?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, Please check now.

Comment: I think you mean NOW() instead of DATE(). Anyhow I'm afraid it's not working for me- it still chooses the latest valid date for the out_time instead of the NULL.

Comment: Sorry, no. It still chooses the latest valid date for the out_time instead of the NULL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT person, MAX(in_time) AS in_time, out_time AS out_time 
FROM checkin_times  
GROUP BY person
ORDER BY person;
```

Comment: I don't want to remove the null out_times. I want to show them if they correspond to the latest in_times.

Comment: This is closer to what I want. It's just that I don't want the NULL out_time to get converted to the latest time in the output. It needs to stay as NULL.

Comment: @Urbycoz Did you check with latest query ?

Comment: I don't think it's quite right. I think without the MAX bit, the out_time just shows the first time it finds. (Maybe some MySQL guru will confirm or correct me on that).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86767/discussion-between-ktanj-and-urbycoz).